# construction of "swimming pool"

Tags: word-usage

This post is derived from a meta post [(“review close votes” sounds grammatically incorrect)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345176/714660), 
 where an answerer considers "swimming" as a verb.

[image]

I'm afraid I cannot agree with that. So, I said there

> "Swimming" is a gerund, not a verb. A gerund could be used as an adjective, a verb cannot.

Is my understanding right? Is that the way the compound noun "swimming pool" constructed, `gerund + noun = compound noun`?

Comment: @Fermichem I agree with you, a gerund should be treated as a noun. I misunderstood that until you saved me. Thank you. So, the pattern of the construction is `participle + noun = compound noun`, right?

Comment: I'd say participle + noun = noun phrase. since you need: noun + noun = compound noun and clearly participles are not nouns  they function as adjectives or adverbs

Comment: @Fermichem Hold on. Things get weird. If "swimming" is treated as a gerund, which functions as a noun, then "swimming pool" fits the pattern `noun + noun = compound noun`, right?

Comment: check out the answer, I hope it serves to clarify the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an in-depth look at gerunds, present participles and the difference between them:

> Gerunds are words that are formed with verbs but act as nouns
>
> Present participles do not act as nouns. Instead, they act as modifiers or complete progressive verbs.

Thus, gerunds will be subjects, subject complements, direct objects, indirect objects, and objects of prepositions. Present participles, on the other hand, are complete progressive verbs(for example in present continuous, "he's swimming" or act as modifiers (as in, swimming pool).

ref: https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds/

ref: https://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm

So, I guess we can agree that "swimming" in "swimming pool" modifies the noun "pool", I.E. it's a modifier and since gerunds can't be modifiers, "swimming" has to be a present participle (by process of elimination!)

Comment: It can't be a [Noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)?

Comment: Unless the pool itself is doing the swimming, I don't see how the participle interpretation can possibly make more sense than the gerund interpretation.